# Sharepoints 2007 Web parts Longitude search

Tags: sharepoint

A tool (SharePoint.Admin) has been written to catalog all the web parts used within Connect.

The tool fails when enumerating the Team Sites collection because of an error with the Longitude Web Parts on a Team Site.

Unfortunately the error is fatal and cannot be caught.

This is required to aid the SharePoint Migration project as it is vital to note all the web parts used in the 2007 environment.

We have 'n' of sites under connect intranet sites.

How do I find the sites using Longitude Web Parts in Team Sites

Comment: If this is about Longitude WebParts why don't you ask the company behind it? www.bainsight.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small script to get all instances of a particular WebPart on all sites:

[Sharepoint: how can i find all the pages that host a particular web part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633633/sharepoint-how-can-i-find-all-the-pages-that-host-a-particular-web-part)

There is no easier way, you need to instantiate `SPLimitedWebPartManager` for each page you have and look for your particular webpart on that page. You only have to extend the method to not query one `SPSite` but all your required sites and web applications.